# `responses` with `requests` retry handling

Tags: python, python-requests, python-responses

I'm attempting to implement/test request retrying within my module - below is a scratch which has the base functionality of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
import responses

retry_strategy = Retry(
    total=3,
    status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504],
    method_whitelist=["HEAD", "GET", "OPTIONS"]
)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy)
http = requests.Session()
http.mount("https://", adapter)
http.mount("http://", adapter)

with responses.RequestsMock() as rsps:
    rsps.add(responses.GET,
             "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php",
             status=502)

    response = http.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php")
    print(len(rsps.calls))
print(response)
```

The base setup is from [this article](https://findwork.dev/blog/advanced-usage-python-requests-timeouts-retries-hooks/), although is used elsewhere on stackoverflow.

I'd expect `len(rsps.calls)` to be 3, since this from my understanding is the amount of retries we would attempt before giving up. However, the output is instead;

```
1
<Response [502]>
```

Is this due to the setup with responses, or is my initial configuration incorrect?

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Retries are not allowed for responses.RequestsMock(). It is a limitation.

Comment: Ah, it seems this is a known issue documented here - https://github.com/getsentry/responses/issues/135

Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not looking for the number of calls, but the number of performed retries. if that is the case, I assume that the answer will be `response.raw.retries.history`

I've found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58002114/history-of-retries-using-request-library)