# Count number of retries for each request

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I use package `requests` together with `urllib3.util.retry.Retry()` to send tens of thousands of queries. I seek to count the number of queries and the number of necessary attempts until I successfully retrieve the desired data. My goal is to construct a measure for the reliability of the API.

To fix ideas, let's assume that the Response object of `requests` contains this data:

```py
from requests import Session
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

def create_session():
    session = Session()
    retries = Retry(
        total = 15,
        backoff_factor = 0.5,
        status_forcelist = [401, 408, 429, 500, 502, 504],
        allowed_methods = frozenset(["GET"])
    )

    session.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
    session.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

    return session

urls = ['https://httpbin.org/status/500']
count_queries = len(urls)
count_attempts = 0

with create_session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        response = s.get(url)
        count_attempts += response.total_retries
```

Since there is no such variable, I am looking for alternatives to count the total number of retries.

While I am unable to identify an approach to this problem, I made the following observations during my search which is potentially helpful:

- `urllib3` stores the retry-history in the Retry object. The `urllib3.HTTPResponse` stores the last Retry object ([docs](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/1dd0613b610df1269dbc11e9780b0fe7debaff3c/CHANGES.rst#117-2016-09-06)). The `urllib3.HTTPResponse` (to be precise, its undecoded body) is stored in `requests.Response.raw`, however only when `stream=True` ([docs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#id5)). In my understanding, I can't access this data.
- One user provides a solution to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188661/adding-callback-function-on-each-retry-attempt-using-requests-urllib3) that subclasses the `Retry` class. Essentially, a callback function is called which prints a string to a logger. This could be adapted to increment a counter instead of printing to logs. However, if possible, I prefer to track the retries specific to a particular `get`, as shown above, as opposed to all `get`s using the same session.
- A very similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58002114/history-of-retries-using-request-library), however no (working) solution was provided.

I'm using Python 3.9, urllib3 1.26.8, requests 2.26.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather verbose solution along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51254525/3484568). It counts requests and retries on the session level (which, however, was not my preferred approach).

```
import requests
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry

class RequestTracker:
    """ track queries and retries """
    def __init__(self):
        self._retries = 0
        self._queries = 0

    def register_retry(self):
        self._retries += 1

    def register_query(self):
        self._queries += 1

    @property
    def retries(self):
        return self._retries

    @property
    def queries(self):
        return self._queries

class RetryTracker(Retry):
    """ subclass Retry to track count of retries """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._request_tracker = kwargs.pop('request_tracker', None)
        super(RetryTracker, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def new(self, **kw):
        """ pass additional information when creating new Retry instance """
        kw['request_tracker'] = self._request_tracker
        return super(RetryTracker, self).new(**kw)
    
    def increment(self, method, url, *args, **kwargs):
        """ register retry attempt when new Retry object with incremented counter is returned """
        if self._request_tracker:
            self._request_tracker.register_retry()
        return super(RetryTracker, self).increment(method, url, *args, **kwargs)

class RetrySession(requests.Session):
    """ subclass Session to track count of queries """
    def __init__(self, retry):
        super().__init__()
        self._requests_count = retry

    def prepare_request(self, request):
        """ increment query counter """
        # increment requests counter
        self._requests_count.register_query()
        return super().prepare_request(request)

class RequestManager:
    """ manage requests """    
    def __init__(self, request_tracker=None):
        # session settings
        self.__session = None
        self.__request_tracker = request_tracker

        # retry logic specification
        args = dict(
            total = 11,
            backoff_factor = 1,
            status_forcelist = [401,408, 429, 500, 502, 504],
            allowed_methods = frozenset(["GET"])
        )
        if self.__request_tracker is not None:
            args['request_tracker'] = self.__request_tracker
            self.__retries = RetryTracker(**args)
        else:
            self.__retries = Retry(**args)
    
    @property
    def session(self):
        if self.__session is None:
            # create new session
            if self.__request_tracker is not None:
                self.__session = RetrySession(self.__request_tracker)
            else:
                self.__session = requests.Session()
            
            # mount https adapter with retry logic
            https = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=self.__retries)
            self.__session.mount('https://', https)
        
        return self.__session
    
    @session.setter
    def session(self, value):
        raise AttributeError('Setting session attribute is prohibited.')

request_tracker = RequestTracker()
request_manager = RequestManager(request_tracker=request_tracker)
session = request_manager.session
urls = ['https://httpbin.org/status/500']

with session as s:
    for url in urls:
        response = s.get(url)

print(request_tracker.queries)
print(request_tracker.retries)
```